# ReactJS->How do i populate my state with the information from within a database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have some JSON lists that look like this:

```
const productsList=[
    {
        name: 'Product1',
        image: productImage,
        price: 36.96,
        quantity: 1,
        id: v4()
    },
    {
        name: 'Product 2',
        image: productImage,
        price: 39.94,
        quantity: 1,
        id:v4()
    },
]
```

That list is then shown on the page using the map function and it is also being stored in the state using mapStateToProps. My question is how can I fill the productsList with the data from within a **sqlite** database?

Comment: Usually between client and the database you have server/api/backend infrastructure so you make request from the client to the server and then the server makes request to database and returns the data back to client. For request from client to server you can use something like axios or fetch js api.

Comment: Can't I, alternatively, also use php to somehow connect the database with the frontend ?

Comment: You can use php to connect to database but php code is executed on the server. Since you are using React you might look into how to separate client and server code so for example you could have client in React that uses axios to makes request to lets say api in php (Laravel or something similar) who then fetches the data from the database and returns response back to the client. So you have 3 layers in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the things you need:

- You need a backend API service that connects to the SQLite database. If you use a Node.js backend, you can use [this library](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3).
- Once it's setup and running, you need to add the code to your frontend React app for fetching the data from your server. You can use hooks to achieve it.

I can't write every line of the code that you need since it's a lot. Hopefully this gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to create an API for the JSON data and have your URL-endpoint.
2. Then use ** Redux-Thunk Library** to make an asynchronous API call to the URL-ENDPOINT and update your **Reducer** as per the API action call and hence your state in the application.

The art of creating API is what backend developers do.